# How can I enable the swagger ui on a jhipster app in prod profile?

Tags: java, swagger, jhipster

I'd like to be able to see the swagger rest api documentation in my jhipster app, even while it is running under the prod profile.  Currently it only shows in the dev profile and I'm not sure where this is configured.

Comment: if you enable it as per zapl answer, you can see it by pointing to `/swagger-ui/index.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swagger configuration is in [`config/apidoc/SwaggerConfiguration.java`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/config/apidoc/SwaggerConfiguration.java)

You could simply remove the line that excludes the prod profile:

```
@Profile("!"+Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)
```

Comment: In order to see the API option in the jhipster nav bar, I also had to remove the ng-hide="inProduction" attribute from the <li> tag in navbar.html

Comment: Please note that swagger does not work with all authentication schemes that JHipster supports, this is why it is disabled in production

Answer (score 5):

In the latest release add ths code to application.prod.yml

```
profiles:
  include: 
    -swagger
```

Comment: there is a case (heroku) where this will not help, see my explanation below

Answer (score 4):

In JHipster version 4.5.6, with Maven, you can enable swagger profiles directly:

> ./mvnw -Pprod,swagger

With Gradle, you can also use those profiles directly:

> ./gradlew -Pprod -Pswagger

*Please note that by default, the swagger profile is disabled in prod and enabled in dev by setting the spring.profiles.include property in application.yml.*

For more information, refer [jhipster profiles](http://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/)

Comment: it should be api-docs not swagger for newer versions, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69745478/175554

Answer (score 2):

No, never do that. Please see ***webapp/app/app.constants.js*** file. It will be generated **automatically** when you are run gulp command. If you want to show Swagger API, please look into that file.

```
(function () {
"use strict";
// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE
angular.module("sosickApp")

.constant("ENV", "dev")

.constant("VERSION", "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")

;
})();
```

And gulpfile.js task:

```
gulp.task('ngconstant:dev', function () {
return ngConstant({
    dest: 'app.constants.js',
    name: 'sosickApp',
    deps: false,
    noFile: true,
    interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
    wrap:
        '(function () {\n' +
        '    "use strict";\n' +
        '    // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n' +
        '    {%= __ngModule %}\n' +
        '})();\n',
    constants: {
        ENV: 'dev',
        VERSION: util.parseVersion()
    }
})
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

with jhipster 7.3.0

```
./mvnw -Pprod,api-docs
```

you should see the log below

```
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'APP' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:9099/
        External:       http://127.0.0.1:9099/
        Profile(s):     [prod, api-docs]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

and in admin panel you can see the API under the menu
[image]

Comment: What if the jhipster application is generated using --no-client option?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too to answer, but on the current JHipster, it can be enabled via command line args or via 2 files:

- application.yml

> ```
> spring:
> profiles:
>     active: dev
>     include:
>         - swagger
> ```

- application-profile.ts
  Find some lines with isSwaggerEnabled then change to true

  > isSwaggerEnabled: true

Then you can access via /swagger-ui/index.html on browser
Hope this helps

Comment: Am I right, that TypeScript part is just for enabling-disabling the link? I see this variable in the code of generator node modules, but not actually in the code, so it turns to be added the last year only?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who is here because want to google out why the swagger isn't enabled on prod in heroku installation despite of setting it a correct `swagger` profile property as in the answers here into `application-prod.yml`, `application-heroku.yml`, `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env variable, `mvn` start-up parameters in `MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS` env variable in `heroku:config` custom env variables...

It looks like the actual profile that will be used by the heroku prod run is in `Procfile`. So I have to change it after tried all the possibilities above. Hope this message will save someone's time.

Enabling swagger to prod isn't a good practise, but actually is ok for out business needs, so we even don't try to make it private.

Answer (score 1):

with jhipster 7.4.1 and Heroku:
Edit your `Procfile`

Instead of

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Xmx256m -jar target/*.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod,heroku
```

Put this

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Xmx256m -jar target/*.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod,api-docs,heroku
```

I.e. add `api-docs` to active profiles.

I can now see Administration / API menu in PROD

Answer (score 0):

Latest JHipster is allowed setting to show/hide Swagger API.